# Programmatically get framework ID

Tags: playframework

Does anybody know if there is a way to programmatically get the current framework ID?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can get the attribute on Play class

```
Play.id
```

Comment: That was easy :-) Is it documented somewhere? I knew it was possible to use Play.configuration(<property_name>) to get properties defined in the configuration file but I could not find anything to access the framework id. Thanks.

Comment: @Clément - Stack Overflow *is* the documentation :) Well, I'm somewhat kidding, but I see a lot of Play info lying around in Stack Overflow ... which is a good thing, since it's a very dynamic platform. I wonder why there isn't a community edited wiki.