# How to get the Framework ID programatically?

Tags: java, playframework

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programmatically get framework ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414086/programmatically-get-framework-id)

I'm using the [Framework ID](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/current/ids) to distinguish between prod and dev enviornments.

How do I access this ID programatically?

Comment: why dont you set a property in application.conf, different values for different environments and use that ?

Comment: @Codemwnci - Sorry I missed it, my Google fu didn't find it.

Comment: @aishwarya - because for my purposes it's easier just querying the framework ID. It's just for a silly hack, nothing serious.

Answer (score 2):

Silly me, I believe it is simply `Play.id`.